# How do I validate a form using an object initializer?

Tags: javascript

I am performing basic form validation using the code below and am wanting to achieve the same result using an object initializer. I am looking at other ways of coding the validation of the form. I am unsure whether there is an added advantage in using an object as opposed to an array. This lack of knowledge is because I am new to the world of javascript.

**Code**

```
var formID = document.forms["webform"];
function validateForm() {
        var formFields = ["salutations", "fname", "lname"];
        var formLabel = ["Salutations", "First Name", "Last Name"];

        for(var i = 0; i < formFields.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (formID[formFields[i]].value.length == 0) {
                window.alert("The field " + formLabel[i] + " is empty");
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "object initializer"?  Are you talking about a constructor function (`function(){ this.something = 1; }`) or just a plain old object (`{some_key: some_value}`) with some methods attached?

Comment: @Sean Vieira - Sorry I mean var sample = {somekey: somevalue}. I am looking at how I could leverage an object oriented design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OO is probably overkill for this. Reuse can be accomplished by passing the `formFields` and `formLabels` into `validateForm`:

```
function validateForm(form, fields, labels) {
    for(var i = 0, l=fields.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (form[fields[i]].value.length === 0) {
            alert("The field " + labels[i] + " is empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also pass all the variables you need in as an object:

```
function alternateValidateForm(options) {
    var form = options.form,
        fields = options.fields,
        labels = options.labels;
    // The remainder of the code is the same
}
```

However, if you want / need an OO pattern then simply create a constructor function:

```
function Validator(fields, labels) {
     this.fields = fields;
     this.labels = labels;
}

Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
    // Same dance as before
}
```

This could then be used in this manner:

```
var validator = new Validator(["salutations", "fname", "lname"],
                              ["Salutations", "First Name", "Last Name"]);
var form = document.getElementById("webform");
validator.validate(form);
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that I could pass multiple values into a single parameter e.g `["salutations", "fname", "lname"` being the argument for the parameter `fields`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - what you are passing is a single parameter.  It is an array, containing three string values, but it is a single array :-)

Comment: Something new to learn. I didn't think it was possible to pass an array to a parameter.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - not only arrays, but objects and functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example.

```
function ValidateForm(form_id, filed_label) {
  this.form = document.forms[form_id];
  this.filed_label = filed_label;
}

ValidateForm.prototype.validate = function () {
  for (var filed in this.filed_label) {
    if (this.form[filed].value.length == 0) {
      window.alert("The field " + this.filed_label[field] + " is empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// usage
new ValidateForm(
  "webform", 
  {
    salutations: "Salutations",
    fname: "First Name",
    lname: "Last Name"
  }
).validate();
```

Comment: Whoa! It wasn't something I was expecting. Will have to break it down. Is there any added advantage with this approach?

Comment: A bit too much PHP perhaps (`->validate()`) ;-)

Comment: @SeanVieira OmG, maybe I should have a cup of coffee, fixed :)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey This is the basic way of doing OO programming in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JavaScript is an object; however, the semantics are super different depending on how you use the language. In this case, you can use an object literal (also referred to as a singleton object).

Using a function constructor in this context doesn't buy you anything useful. Definitely use the constructor function pattern when it is necessary, but otherwise, there is no need.

Hopefully the following will be easy to follow. You will also note that we are adding the field title into the markup for better code reuse. We might have used a label element, but that is a minor detail that can be changed at any time.

Form HTML:

```
​<form name="webform" id="webform">
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" title="Full Name" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="return window.validate();" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Validation:

```
var Form = Form || {};

Form.validate = function (config){
    var form  = document.getElementById(config.id);
    var valid = true;

    config.fields.forEach(function(field){
        if (!form[field].value.length) {valid = false;}
    });

    return valid;
};
```

Using:

```
window.validate = function () {
    var valid = Form.validate({id: 'webform', fields: ['fullname']});
    console.log('Valid Form?', valid);
}
​
```

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/au2fx/